# Propositional Logic Problems

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Im struggling with the following problems. In each case determine whether the statement is true or false.

a)

> $(A \implies B) \iff C \models A \lor \neg B \lor C$

b)

> $(\neg A \implies \neg B) \land (A \land \neg B)$ is satisfiable.

c)

> $(\neg A \iff \neg B) \land (A \land \neg B)$.

Part b) I believe is true as it will hold for certain combinations of true/false for A and B. From my understanding if the statement is satisfiable then it is also true, meaning c) is also true?

I have not been able to make much progress on part a).

Comment: b) is correct....

Comment: What does it mean that c) is true ? Tautology ?

Comment: For a) use truth table. If you can find a row in the tt where the premise is True and the conclusion is False, this means that the argument is not valid.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Not a tautology. Simply determining whether the expression evaluates to true or false.

Comment: Well (c) can output both true and false values, try $A = \top, B = \bot$ and $A = \bot, B = \bot$

Comment: A formula is evaluated to T or F by a specific truth assignment (a line in the truth table). Without specifying the assignment, how can we answer ?

Comment: "From my understanding if the statement is satisfiable then it is also true, meaning c) is also true?"  No.  If a statement is falsifiable then it *could* be true .. it doesn't mean that it *is* true.  As others have pointed out, it is not clear what the claim is with regard to c) ... and if it is, as you say, to figure out whether the expression evaluates to true or false, we are not provided with enough information.  Can you please check the question as it was given to you?

Answer (score 0):

(A) In order to prove that $$(A \rightarrow B) \iff C \tag{1}$$ tautologically implicate $$A  \vee \neg B \vee C  \tag{2}$$

You will need to prove that for every interpretation where (1) is true - (2) is true as well. Meaning that if you find an interpretation that makes (1) true and (2) false you can say (a) is not true. One way of doing it is by constructing a truth table, the second option is to prove

$$ ((A \rightarrow B) \iff C) \rightarrow A \vee \neg B \vee C$$

Is a tautology. I would prefer this way, because it is very straight forward, as I said, if this tautological implication is not correct (false) then we can find a line where $ A \vee \neg B \vee C$ is false.

This proposition evaluates to "false" if and only if $A = \bot, B = \top , C = \bot$ because otherwise, it would be true (as we have a DNF)
Plugging those values to (1) we get it also evaluates to false, meaning the logical implication is evaluated to true ( $\bot \rightarrow \bot \equiv \top$)

Other interpretation of $A,B,C$ would make (2) true - and that means the logical implication would also be true, so there is no need to check these interpretations.